# Connected components in R

Tags: r

I have a 3 dim binary array and want to locate and retrieve the connected components.
I looked into the documentation of the "igraph" package but it seemed to only consider matrices.Did I miss a function relative to my problem?
Thank you.

(edit) example

```
> a=replicate(4,rnorm(4))
> a[a>0]=1
> a[a<0]=0
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    1
 [2,]    0    0    0    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0
```

In this 2 dim example 3 blobs are created.
     [1,1],
     [1:2,4],
     [3,1:3] U [4,3]

Package igraph seems to be able to handle connectivity in 2 dim.I'm wondering if it can
handle it in 3.

Comment: @ Euripides Epik: Welcome to the SO.Can you please post the [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you.Added a 2 dim example